# Why don't I see my programmatically generated image in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to generate the image programmatically, so using an  tag in the xaml isn't an option. I tried also to run at, when the window is loaded, but

Running the program just gives me a blank screen:

My .CS

```
namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public Image anImage;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            anImage = new Image();
            anImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            anImage.Width = 120;
            anImage.Height = 310;
            anImage.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
            anImage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
            anImage.Margin = new Thickness(500, 500, 0, 0);
            BitmapImage bmImage = new BitmapImage();
            bmImage.BeginInit();
            bmImage.UriSource = new Uri("balloonB.png", UriKind.Relative);
            bmImage.EndInit();
            anImage.Source = bmImage;
            anImage.Stretch = Stretch.None;

            this.AddVisualChild(anImage);
            this.InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1024" Width="1280" ResizeMode="NoResize"
                 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid Width="1280" Height="1024">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Does the output window in visual studio has any info?

Comment: set the window content instead of adding the visual.  (this.Content = anImage;)   However that will negate your grid.  Otherwise add the image to the grid's children (after giving the grid a name).

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Stack Overflow. Secondly, *some more details... some more details... some more details... some more details...* doesn't cut it here. Please edit your question, removing the nonsense and adding a proper description of your problem. Please also read through the Stack Overflow [Help Centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see how else you can improve your question and therefore, your likelihood of receiving a decent answer.

Comment: No, the output window has no comment, and this.Content has no effect. Every example I looked up in the web is using an <image ...> tag inside the <Grid  ...> in the xaml, maybe generating an image programmatically didn't work? And Yes, this is my first C# program...

Comment: I did add an answer but frankly, this tutorial will tell you everything http://tech.pro/tutorial/856/wpf-tutorial-using-a-visual-collection

Comment: Are you sure that your path to the image is correct?

Comment: @Gusdor Do you really think that programming the WPF Visual Layer is the right suggestion for an apparent WPF newbie?

Comment: @Clemens I take your point. I wanted to offer a solution that would get the existing code working but neglected the easy solution. Yours suggests a large refactor but is valuable for a newbie. +1

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two things wrong with your code.

First, you should make sure that the image file can be loaded at runtime. The easiest way is to add the file to your Visual Studio project, perhaps in a folder named "Images". The Build Action of the file has to be set to `Resource`, but this is the default for image files anyway. Now you can access this image resource file in code behind by means of a [Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) (or a [Resource Pack URI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly) to be more precise). Given the folder name "Images", that URI would look like this:

```
pack://application:,,,/Images/balloonB.png
```

Second, you should not use `AddVisualChild` to add the Image control to your MainWindow. Instead, add it to the top-level Grid by setting the `x:Name` attribute on the Grid in XAML, and then using the auto-generated member variable with that name in code-behind.

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid x:Name="rootGrid" Width="1280" Height="1024">
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Add the Image control to the Grid:

```
rootGrid.Children.Add(anImage);
```

Putting it all together and omitting unnecessary property settings, your code would look like this:

```
var anImage = new Image();
anImage.Width = 120;
anImage.Height = 310;
anImage.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
anImage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
anImage.Margin = new Thickness(500, 500, 0, 0);
anImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/balloonB.png"));
rootGrid.Children.Add(anImage);
```

Or, a little shorter:

```
var anImage = new Image
{
    Width = 120,
    Height = 310,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    Margin = new Thickness(500, 500, 0, 0),
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/balloonB.png"))
};
rootGrid.Children.Add(anImage);
```

Comment: OK, it works, the point I missed was that I didn't put the image file inside the projectmap.

Comment: @wischi Then you should accept the answer (by clicking the check mark on the left below the vote counter). That would mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I find many times that a full pack Uri is a bit much and that a simplified Uri works just as well if not better, just be sure that your image build property is configured as MSBuild Resource:

```
Image anImage = new Image();
anImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
anImage.Width = 120;
anImage.Height = 310;
anImage.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
anImage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
BitmapImage bmImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/yournameSpace;component/Subfolder/balloonB.png"));
bmImage.BeginInit();
bmImage.EndInit();
anImage.Source = bmImage;
anImage.Stretch = Stretch.None;
gr.Children.Add(anImage);
```

## Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1024" Width="1280" ResizeMode="NoResize"
                 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid Name="gr" Width="1280" Height="1024">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Did you run the example code?

Comment: -1 for repeating the AddVisualChild and InvalidateVisual garbage. Fix that and provide a few more details about image resource files and Pack URIs (perhaps with [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx#Resource_File_Pack_URIs___Local_Assembly)), and I'll be happy to remove my downvote.

Comment: Ok i edit it and i ll be glad for @wischi if you could help him with answer -_-

Comment: Now you have to explain what `gr` is.

Comment: That's clear it represents the controls that he wants to add the image inside it. Again, i will be happy if you can provide us with your splendid answer.

Comment: Why don't you *just show* what it is? OP is apparently a WPF newbie, and I'm pretty sure that to him it is not that clear as to you what you mean with `gr`. Maybe it would it be ok for you if I edit your answer? It's only a few but important points missing.

Comment: Ok i saw your answer you just rewrote what i just write

Comment: You wrote exactly one sentence that honestly sounds a little confusing. The rest is sample code and XAML. No explanations at all. Really a poor answer. However, I removed my downvote because you managed to get rid of the AddVisualChild nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with this line:

```
anImage.Margin = new Thickness(500, 500, 0, 0);
```

I renamed my Grid to gr and tried the following code and it works, I used the ImageBrush to draw the image:

```
Image anImage = new Image();
anImage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
anImage.Width = 120;
anImage.Height = 310;
anImage.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
anImage.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top;
//anImage.Margin = new Thickness(500, 500, 0, 0);
BitmapImage bmImage = new BitmapImage();
bmImage.BeginInit();
bmImage.UriSource = new Uri("balloonB.png", UriKind.Relative);
bmImage.EndInit();

ImageBrush ib = new ImageBrush(bmImage);
anImage.Source = ib.ImageSource;
gr.Children.Add(anImage);
```

## Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1024" Width="1280" ResizeMode="NoResize"
                 WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized">
    <Grid Name="gr" Width="1280" Height="1024">

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It really worked on yours? I copied your lines just below InitializeComponents(); inside the public MainWindow() and see no image still, also tried with this.InvalidateVisuals();

Comment: The ImageBrush is nonsense. Just assign `anImage.Source = bmImage;`.

Comment: @Claudio You should also show the XAML with the *named Grid*, as OP might not know what you mean.